# Mark class property as a generic but of a type unknown for the moment in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

In following interface, there is `linkedTitle` property that contains a link to another instance of it's own interface but the type of `Title<>` could be different.

```
export interface Title<T> {
  data: {
    description: string;
    presentation: string;
    value: T;
  };
  linkedTitle: Title;
  //           ^^^^^ Generic type 'Title<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

  name: string;
  presentation: string;
  type: number;
}
```

How to pass the type to `linkedTitle`?

Comment: I mean, maybe this is naïve, but does `Title<unknown>` work for you like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdoXyw)?  If it doesn't, could you show a [mre] of a use case where that fails?

Comment: How do you expect this to actually be used? You could make the generic type argument optional with e.g. `T = any`, but given the recursive nature it's going to be very tricky to do something type-safe.

Comment: You can have a default value for the generic if you define it like that `interface Title<T = unknown> {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just building on @Matthieu Riegler's comment. I guess what I want is following.

```js
export interface Title<T = string | number| boolean> {
  data: {
    description: string;
    presentation: string;
    value: T;
  };
  linkedTitles: Title;
  name: string;
  presentation: string;
  type: number;
}
```

Though following solutions are also working as suggested

```js
export interface Title<T> {
  data: {
    description: string;
    presentation: string;
    value: T;
  };
  linkedTitles: Title<unknown>;
  name: string;
  presentation: string;
  type: number;
}
```

```js
export interface Title<T = unknown> {
  data: {
    description: string;
    presentation: string;
    value: T;
  };
  linkedTitles: Title;
  name: string;
  presentation: string;
  type: number;
}
```

Comment: You say you want `string | number | boolean` but that isn't mentioned in the question; for this to be a good q/a pair, could you edit the question so that you specify that `T` should default to `string | number | boolean`?  Do you want to support `Title<Date>` or something where `T` is not constrained to `string | number | boolean`?  If not, then you want a constraint as well as a default, maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7OkGN).